# Please help me prove a positive definite matrix!

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, nonnegative-matrices

Prove that:
 If $W$ is a [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) having positive diagonal elements and size $(2^n–1)\text{x}(2^n – 1)$, $K$ is a matrix with size $(2^n – 1)\text{x}n$, then:
$A = K^T[W^{-1} - K(K^TWK)^{-1}K^T]K$
is a *[positive definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix)*.
Using the Monte-Carlo method, I find that the matrix
 $B=W^{-1} - K(K^TWK)^{-1}K^T$
 can be negative definite.
Thank you so much for reading my question
I am looking forward to getting your response!

Comment: I don't think this is true.  You matrix should be positive semidefinite, but not negative definite.  Maybe your Monte Carlo experiments did not handle roundoff errors correctly, that is, maybe some computed eigenvalues were floating point approximations to 0, such as 1.3e-18, etc?

Comment: @kimchilover Matlab has a function *chol* for checking positively defined matrices, I think it works correctly. The number of trials in the Monte Carlo method was large (10^5). In each test, I generated a diagonal matrix W having random positive diagonal elements and a random matrix K. Then, using the function *chol*, it was found that the matrix B is negative definite in some cases, and the matrix A is always positive definite.<br/>
Then my question is: is it possible to prove that A is *positive definite matrix*? <br/>

Answer (score 1):

I assume you assume that   $K^TWK$ is invertible; I do too.

Let $W^{1/2}$ be a symmetric square root of $W$, and let $L=W^{1/2}K$.  Then $$W^{1/2}BW^{1/2} =I-L(K^TWK)^{-1}L^T = I-L(L^TL)^{-1}L^T.$$
This is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the null space of $L$, and hence
positive semi definite.

In more detail:  write the singular value decomposition $L=P\Delta Q$ where $\Delta$ is diagonal, and  $Q$ is $n\times n$, we see that $$L(L^TL)^{-1}L'=(U\Delta V)(V^T\Delta^2V)^{-1}(V^T\Delta U^T) = UU^T.$$  Note that $\|U^Tx\|^2\le\|x\|^2$ so  $x^T(I-UU^T)x=\|x\|^2-\|U^Tx\|^2\ge0$, verifying the psd claim.

Since $Q^{1/2}$ is invertible, $B$ is also semi positive definite.

I assume the contradiction between this and what the OP asked for is due to
a mismatch between the posted question and the Matlab code it describes.